# regex to extract url from google search

Tags: regex, perl, url, html-parsing

I need extract a url from a google search , i try this:

```
if($google =~ /<h3 class="r"><a href="(.*)"/i){
print "$1\n$2\n$3\n$4\n$5\n$6\n$7\n$8\n$9\n$10";
}
```

But is this wrong , please help me ;-)

Comment: You only have one capture, but you're printing what was captured by the first, second, third, ..., ninth and tenth captures.

Comment: i'm... amazing. your fingers do more work that i can imagine!  `print join("\n",map{"$".$_}(1..10))`

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules.

Comment: @loldop, `"$1"` and `"$".1` (if it wouldn't be a syntax error it would be `"\$1"`) are not the same. ;-)

Comment: @Qtax yeah, i need eval, but... his fingers are crazy:)

Comment: look at the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908989/extract-text-from-search-result-urls-using-r/45910514?noredirect=1#comment78818195_45910514)

Comment: Now I know a better way ```@urls = $body =~ /<h3 class="r"><a href="([^"]+)/g;```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($google =~ /<h3 class="r"><a href="(.*?)"/ig)
{
  print "$1\n";
}
```

Notice that you need set `~//g` (global search) for going to next mach in while loop.
Also use `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)`, otherway you will have in $1 whole page till to last quote at the page