# Web scraping with rvest - Unexpected behaviour

Tags: r, rvest

I would like to scrape all the links from this web page with `rvest`: http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15

I have tried with the following:

```
library(rvest)

url <- read_html('http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15')
nodes <- html_nodes(x = url, css = 'a') %>%
         html_attr('href')
```

Rather than getting all of them, I only got 3. I had a look at the HTML structure of the page and there are definitely more links - particularly in the table.

I then tried to get those ones - the table is in the `block_content` div:

```
url <- read_html('http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15')
nodes <- html_nodes(x = url, css = '.block_content') %>%
         html_attr('href')
```

I didn't get any. How do I go ahead?

Comment: The first link in your question is different from the one in the code. The first one ends in 1 but in the code it ends in 15.

Comment: I'll amend that right away. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
url   <- 'http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/1'

require(XML)
doc <- htmlParse(url)
links <- xpathSApply(doc, "//a/@href")

links
```

> ```
>                                                                                                      href 
>                                                                                        "#contentIntCenter" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                                   "#menu2" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                    "http://www.interno.it" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                              "/index.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                 "/ser/revisori_intro.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                        "/docum/index.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                          "/ser/index.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                 "/ser/revisori_intro.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                       "/apps/revisori.php/corsi_condivisi" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                       "/ser/revisori/rev_datisintesi.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                         "/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                "/apps/revisori.php/situazione_organo_ente" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                            "/apps/revisori.php/get_estraz" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                  "/apps/revisori.php/enti_organo_scadenza" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                              "/apps/revisori.php/register" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                       "/apps/revisori.php" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                               "/ser/revisori/rev_faq.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                         "/ser/revisori/rev_circolari.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                        "/ser/revisori/rev_comunicati.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                         "/ser/revisori/rev_algoritmo.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                        "/ser/revisori/rev_contributo.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                          "/ser/revisori/rev_comefare.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                          "/ser/revisori/rev_contatti.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                     "/ser/tbel_intro.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                                        "#" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                "/ser/revisori/20170711_16990elencorev.pdf" 
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/28366#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/31365#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/13681#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/33752#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/11324#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/38169#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/29081#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/27175#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/36459#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/21036#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/31852#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/13244#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
>  "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/4532#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/32139#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
> "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/0/idA/10652#combo1"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                                        "#" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                 "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
>                 "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/30"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
>                 "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/45"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
>                 "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/60"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
>                 "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/75"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
>                 "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
>              "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/16980"
>
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                                  "#inizio" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                                        "#" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                                        "#" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                                        "#" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                                        "#" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                        "/note_legali.html" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                          "http://www.gazzettaufficiale.it" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                                 "http://www.italia.gov.it" 
>                                                                                                       href 
>                                                                            "http://www.governoitaliano.it"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
url=read_html("http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15")

url%>%html_nodes("a")%>%html_attr("href")%>%grep(pattern="http",value=T)
```

for more information on how to do this please look at another example solved 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45908989/extract-text-from-search-result-urls-using-r/45910514#45910514)

> [1] "http://www.interno.it"
>    [2] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/1512#combo1" 
>    [3] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/37640#combo1"
>    [4] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/5185#combo1" 
>    [5] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/36196#combo1"
>    [6] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/2028#combo1" 
>    [7] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/8882#combo1" 
>    [8] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/18386#combo1"
>    [9] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/354#combo1"
>   [10] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/31841#combo1"
>   [11] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/18165#combo1"
>   [12] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/14787#combo1"
>   [13] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/37955#combo1"
>   [14] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/37414#combo1"
>   [15] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/13739#combo1"
>   [16] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15/idA/11640#combo1"
>   [17] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/"
>   [18] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/1/"
>   [19] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/30"
>   [20] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/45"
>   [21] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/60"
>   [22] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/75"
>   [23] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/90"
>   [24] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/30"
>   [25] "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/16980"
>   [26] "http://www.gazzettaufficiale.it"
>   [27] "http://www.italia.gov.it"
>   [28] "http://www.governoitaliano.it"

Comment: I have edited the code. Try and see whether it gives the expected result

Comment: Hi Onyambu. Thanks a lot. I'm not sure why this bit of code still gives me only 3 links. Have you loaded other libraries? Did you use this link http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/revisori.php/albo_revisori/elencoRevisori/indice/15?

Comment: Yes I am using the url you have posted in your comment. The one ending with 15 That is the url I am using